# MassTransit with RabbitMQ and Message Ordering using keys & direct exchange

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using MassTransit with RabbitMQ and are trying to achieve multiple consumers receiving device messages from a Queue, while achieving message ordering within a single device. We need to be able to scale to up to 20000 devices and more.

We know that this is possible with kafka by using partition keys, and we found that in RabbitMQ we can achieve something similar by using the direct exchange strategy and using our deviceID as the key, EDIT* with a prefetch count of 1 in all consumers. While testing a POC with RabbitMQ, we saw some strange behaviour.

EDIT* Configuration below

Producer Config

```
cfg.Message<DeviceMessage>(e => e.SetEntityName("unit-messages")); // name of the primary exchange
cfg.Publish<DeviceMessage>(e => e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct); // primary exchange type
cfg.Send<DeviceMessage>(e =>
{
  e.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(context => 
  context.Message.DeviceId.ToString()); // route by provider (email 
  or fax)
});
```

Consumer Config

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfUnits; i++) {
  cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("unit-"+i+"-messages", re =>
  {
    // turns off default fanout settings
    re.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

    // a replicated queue to provide high availability and data safety. available in RMQ 3.8+
    re.SetQuorumQueue();

    // enables a lazy queue for more stable cluster with better predictive performance.
    re.SetQueueArgument("declare", "lazy");

    re.PrefetchCount = 1;
    re.Consumer<MessageConsumer>();
    re.Bind("unit-messages", e =>
    {
      e.RoutingKey = "unit-"+i;
      e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
    });
  });
}
```

1. There is sometimes a 1 minute (or more) delay between the end of a consumption of a message, and the beginning of a consumption of the next message. In between these 2 points, there is no activity and no ongoing processing happening. It has already finished consumption of the messages before for all devices, and yet it does not receive the next message until 1 minute later.
2. Sometimes - not consistent - the very first message gets consumed last (all other messages are in order), and usually when that happens, we noticed that there is that 1 minute (or more) delay before that message gets consumed (what was brought up from point number 1).

Any thoughts to this approach and these issues identified?

EDIT* Is RabbitMQ not meant to have that many queues configured with the number of queues dynamically going up and down (whenever a new device gets added or removed).
Should we use Kafka for this type of use case?

Comment: You should clarify this question by adding your configuration and logs. If you're using a single queue with a prefetch count > 1, there is no guarantee of message order. If you're using 20,000 queues, well, that's an entirely different problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just did. How is using 20,000 queues a problem? I guess I am hearing that RabbitMQ is not meant to have that many queues configured?

Comment: I would rather use Kafka, with a single topic, configured with maybe 100-1000 partitions, using the key for the device ID. Then you have ordering, recoverability, and it's designed for that type of workload.

Comment: We already have RabbitMQ configured from previously on this existing project so we want to avoid moving to kafka unless there is a clear reason to. Is there some kind of article explaining why this is not a good idea to implement with RabbitMQ? I guess RabbitMQ is not designed for that type of thing?

Comment: Without seeing logs, channel counts, etc. it's hard to know what will or won't work. 65k is the channel limit, 20k should work, but you'd need to configure it. Not something I would do, but RabbitMQ seems to allow it. Just make sure you're on a sizable RMQ install with a LOT of memory and space available.